# How to price "Lifting ST" with a "Payload Only" limiter?

Tags: character-creation, powers, gurps-4e

Designing a vehicle ally for a super, it has the payload advantage. But I want to buy "Lifting ST" limited to its payload only.

How much (-NN%) would be a "Payload Only" limiter on Lifting ST?

I am also interested in the rationale for the pricing of that limiter.

Answer (score 6):

## Payload already has “I would like more” priced into it

Getting less Payload plus some kind of “Lifting ST (Payload only)” is not the way to model this.

To model most vehicles, you get an appropriate amount of *either* Payload or Lifting ST, depending on how the vehicle works:

> #### Payload
>
> […]
> Machines that can push or pull large *external* loads – or pick them up and carry them with arms, cranes, etc. – have Lifting ST (p. 65), not Payload. Ordinary cars and trucks have Payload, but forklifts, tugboats, and the like should buy Lifting ST to represent their abilities.

If you’re pondering how to get Lifting ST for just Payload because you want a better Basic Lift to calculate the BL/10 per level capacity of Payload, GURPS doesn’t want you to do that — you’re supposed to just buy more levels of Payload directly instead of trying to buy fewer and then getting an advantage with a limiter to make up for the missing levels.

Of course, if your vehicle can manage more external loads than its mass (i.e., ST) would indicate ***and*** it has an internal carrying compartment, then you get both as appropriate to each. Buy up the Lifting ST until it suits the vehicle you’re modelling — first, because it sets BL — then buy up enough levels of Payload to get the internal capacity you’re modelling.